# Is there any way to figure out Chrome's media settings environment by javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, media, autoplay

Is there any way to figure out user's chrome browser media settings environment by javascript?

On Android Chorme browser, user can disable autoplay.

three-dot menu icon in the top right corner of the Chrome app > Settings > Site settings > Media 
(https://9to5google.com/2018/02/15/how-to-disable-autoplay-videos-chrome/)

Is there a way to detect if the user has this automatic playback blocking setting by JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. But you could try to autoplay a video and check if it is playing by reading the [`currentTime`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_currenttime.asp) property.

Maybe something like that.

```
let autoPlayOn = 'waiting for video load..';
const vid = document.getElementById('myVideo');
vid.oncanplay = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        if (vid.currentTime > 0) {
            autoPlayOn = 'yup!';
        } else {
            autoPlayOn = 'nope';
        }
    }, 1000);
};
```